# Can not add user to Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops

We are trying to add a user to DevOps.  Getting following error:
OIDCONFLICT_UpnReuse_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Can anyone shed some light here

Comment: how many users are already there in that project??

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue which you need to contact Microsoft to resolve

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/user-cannot-log-in-to-azure-devops/1120363

The user was able to login after the Microsoft technician remapped the user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  We assigned new email Id to the user and were able to add her.